# How to plot the function correctly like the following?

Tags: plotting

I have a problem like this, I have a scalar function  expressed in elliptic coordinates `ξ`  , and taking a partial derivative of this scalar function gives the velocity field `{vx,vy}`, and then taking curl of the velocity field gets the vortex(anyway a scalar function) . The correctly expected result is that the velocity field `{vx,vy}` is elliptical and the vortex  is  uniform and only inside a bounded ellipse.

After some effort, I finally got the following poor result, I think it is the singularity on `ξ=0 <=> y=0&&x∈[-c,c]`(which c is focal length) caused such a poor result, I don't know if the result can be further processed to make it better/accurate(that means `=const` in a bounded ellipse and `=0` in the remained region) (btw, i try to `Limit[,{y->0}]`, however Mathematica can't give result)

poor result:
[image]

code for your test: (There are two small problems that I expressed in the form of comments，hope you can answer by the way if you want to)

```
Remove["Global`*"]

(*Expression & Transformation from elliptic to cartesian*)
Subscript[\[Psi], o]=-(1/4)\[CapitalOmega] (a+b)^2 E^(-2\[Xi]) Cos[2\[Eta]] - 1/2 a b w \[Xi]; 
Subscript[\[Psi], i]=-(1/2)w(a-b)(b Cosh[\[Xi]]^2 Cos[\[Eta]]^2+a Sinh[\[Xi]]^2 Sin[\[Eta]]^2); 
a=8;b=2;w=1;\[CapitalOmega]=(a b)/(a+b)^2 w; (*parameters for test*)

{Subscript[\[Xi], xy],Subscript[\[Eta], xy]}=CoordinateTransformData["Cartesian"->"Elliptic", "Mapping", {x,y}];
Subscript[\[Psi], o]=(Subscript[\[Psi], o]/.{\[Xi]->Subscript[\[Xi], xy],\[Eta]->Subscript[\[Eta], xy]})/.\[FormalA]->Sqrt[a^2-b^2];
Subscript[\[Psi], i]=(Subscript[\[Psi], i]/.{\[Xi]->Subscript[\[Xi], xy],\[Eta]->Subscript[\[Eta], xy]})/.\[FormalA]->Sqrt[a^2-b^2];

\[Psi]=\[Piecewise]{
 {Subscript[\[Psi], o], x^2/a^2+y^2/b^2>1},
 {Subscript[\[Psi], i], x^2/a^2+y^2/b^2<=1}
};

(*Calculating*)
{vx,vy}={D[\[Psi],y],-D[\[Psi],x]};  (*should be elliptical *)
\[Omega]=Curl[{vx,vy},{x,y}];     (*should be uniform and only inside a bounded ellipse which means zero in other region*)

(*Ploting*)
StreamPlot[{vx,vy},{x,-10,10},{y,-10,10}]  
(*why no result?? and add N[] will have result*)
Plot3D[\[Omega],{x,-10,10},{y,-10,10}]
ContourPlot[\[Omega],{x,-10,10},{y,-10,10}]

StreamPlot[N[{vx,vy}],{x,-10,10},{y,-10,10}] 
Plot3D[N[\[Omega]],{x,-10,10},{y,-10,10}]
ContourPlot[N[\[Omega]],{x,-10,10},{y,-10,10}]

StreamPlot[N[{vx,vy}],{x,-10,10},{y,-10,10},
RegionFunction->Function[{x,y,z},Abs[y]>=1]] 
Plot3D[N[\[Omega]],{x,-10,10},{y,-10,10},
RegionFunction->Function[{x,y,z},Abs[y]>=1]]
ContourPlot[N[\[Omega]],{x,-10,10},{y,-10,10},
RegionFunction->Function[{x,y,z},Abs[y]>=1]]
(*seems RegionFuntion only change "displaying region",
how to change the region Mathematica calculates??*)


(*you can see indeed \[Omega] is bounded in an ellipse*)
Switch[5, 1,(x0=3;y0=1;),       (*interior of the ellipse*)
          2,(x0=4;y0=1;),
          3,(x0=5;y0=1;),
          4,(x0=6;y0=1;),
          5,(x0=7;y0=0.001;),
          6,(x0=7;y0=0;),       (*interior & on the x-axis*)           
          7,(x0=7;y0=1;),       (*exterior of the ellipse *) 
          8,(x0=7;y0=7;),         
          9,(x0=a+0.001;y0=0;)  (*exterior & on the x-axis*) 
          ];{x0,y0} 
(x^2/a^2+y^2/b^2)/.{x->x0,y->y0}
\[Omega]/.{x->x0,y->y0}
N[\[Omega]/.{x->x0,y->y0}]

Limit[\[Omega],{x->4,y->0}] (*can't figure it out，have to abort*)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not expect to do complicated calculations using machine precision. Use arbitrary-precision in the plots by specifying a [`WorkingPrecision`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WorkingPrecision.html)

```
$Version

(* "13.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (November 18, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

(*Expression& Transformation from elliptic to cartesian*)
Subscript[ψ, 
   o] = -(1/4) Ω (a + b)^2 E^(-2 ξ) Cos[2 η] - 
   1/2 a b w ξ;
Subscript[ψ, 
   i] = -(1/2) w(
    a - b) (b Cosh[ξ]^2 Cos[η]^2 + a Sinh[ξ]^2 Sin[η]^2);
a = 8; b = 2; w = 1; Ω = (a b)/(a + 
      b)^2 w; (*parameters for test*)

{Subscript[ξ, xy], Subscript[η, xy]} = 
  CoordinateTransformData["Cartesian" -> "Elliptic", "Mapping", {x, y}];
Subscript[ψ, 
   o] = (Subscript[ψ, 
      o] /. {ξ -> Subscript[ξ, xy], η -> 
       Subscript[η, xy]}) /. \[FormalA] -> Sqrt[a^2 - b^2];
Subscript[ψ, 
   i] = (Subscript[ψ, 
      i] /. {ξ -> Subscript[ξ, xy], η -> 
       Subscript[η, xy]}) /. \[FormalA] -> Sqrt[a^2 - b^2];

ψ = \[Piecewise]{{Subscript[ψ, o], 
     x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 > 1}, {Subscript[ψ, i], x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 <= 1}};

(*Calculating*)
{vx, vy} = {D[ψ, y], -D[ψ, x]} // Simplify;  (*should be elliptical*)
ω = 
  Curl[{vx, vy}, {x, 
    y}];     (*should be uniform and only inside a bounded ellipse which \
means zero in other region*)

StreamPlot[N[{vx, vy}, 20], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10},
 WorkingPrecision -> 20]
```

[image]

```
Plot3D[ω, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10},
 PlotPoints -> 75,
 MaxRecursion -> 2,
 ClippingStyle -> None,
 WorkingPrecision -> 20]
```

[image]

```
ContourPlot[ω, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10},
 MaxRecursion -> 2,
 WorkingPrecision -> 20]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I think this answer is most i need, although a little pity is the singularity on the x∈[-c,c], which c is focal length, still is not well resolved, which is a more math-problem than a Mathematica-problem.